# Issue using Vagrant SSH when vagrant.d folder is on an external exFAT drive

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, exfat

Setting up Vagrant for the first time and I'm using the `VAGRANT_HOME` environment variable to change the location of the `~/.vagrant.d` folder to an external drive (I'm paranoid about SSD wear and tear, sue me).  This is causing an issue with the `vagrant ssh` command as it's complaining about not having the right permissions and I can't use `chmod` to change the permissions for the file it wants on an exFAT volume.

Is there a workaround?  I've checked the documentation and there doesn't seem to be a setting where I can specify a different location for the insecure key, but I might be missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: this is more a question for [superuser](https://superuser.com)

Comment: What do you think of using a symbolic link? To move that folder to another physical location, without changing any env vars

Comment: @bakkal Creating a symbolic link at `~/.vagrant.d` pointing to the external location gives the same error.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to move the `insecure_private_key` file located in the external `vagrant.d` folder to somewhere in your local home directory and then symlink it back.

Comment: Not my question, but ran into a similar situation. this solution worked